# Using a left join where is null in the update statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to use a left join to set the plot.jobs row to 0 when there isn't a match found in the booking table (the check is plot.plot_id = booking.plot_id).

However I keep getting the following error message:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM plot LEFT JOIN booking ON plot.plot_id =
>   booking.plot_id WHERE plot.plot_id' at line 1.

I was following this template here:

```
UPDATE <Table2>
SET Count = 0 
FROM <Table2>
LEFT JOIN <Table1>
    ON <Table2>.<JoinColumn> = <Table1>.<JoinColumn>
WHERE <Table1>.<JoinColumn> IS NULL
```

This is my code so far:

```
query =     "UPDATE plot SET jobs = @jobCount WHERE plot_id = @plotID AND postcode='MK';";
query +=    "UPDATE plot " +
            "SET jobs = 0 " +
            "FROM plot " +
            "LEFT JOIN booking " +
            "ON plot.plot_id = booking.plot_id " +
            "WHERE plot.plot_id IS NULL";
cmd =       new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
```

Comment: don't you see how your code looks nothing like the template?

Comment: @Hogan - sorry question updated

Comment: Check your syntax, You can't have `FROM` directly after `SET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use the SQL Server syntax for `UPDATE` statements on MySQL. This doesn't work.

The [`UPDATE`-syntax of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Where `table_reference` is defined with the [`JOIN`-syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Your query should be something like:

```
query +=    "UPDATE plot " +
            "LEFT JOIN booking " +
            "ON plot.plot_id = booking.plot_id " +
            "SET jobs = 0 " +
            "WHERE plot.plot_id IS NULL";
```

I am wondering if you don't mean: `WHERE booking.plot_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't quite right for MySQL.  Do your `LEFT JOIN` before `SET`

Something like this should work (Note: this hasn't been tested).

```
query +=    "UPDATE plot p" +
            "LEFT JOIN booking b" +
            "ON p.plot_id = b.plot_id " +
            "SET jobs = 0 " +
            "WHERE p.plot_id IS NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to update the plot table setting jobs equal to zero when plot_id is null? What is the point of the join in this case? You are attempting to join records based on a null value which seems highly invalid, and you're not using the joined table booking for anything. I recommend removing the join and the from statement is not valid in an update as Saggio mentioned.

```
query = "UPDATE plot SET jobs = @jobCount WHERE plot_id = @plotID AND postcode='MK';";
query +="UPDATE plot " +
        "SET jobs = 0 " +
        "LEFT JOIN booking ON plot.plot_id = booking.plot_id" +
        "WHERE booking.plot_id IS NULL;";
cmd =   new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
```

Comment: It should be set to 0 if it the plot_id be found in the booking table (i.e. `plot.plot_id = booking.plot_id`)

Comment: Trouble is your where clause is limiting records to only those that have a null plot_id. You are effectively saying that you want to update all plots which have no id.

Comment: ...Okay okay I think I get what you're trying to do. You'll want to still exclude the FROM statement, I'll add the RIGHT JOIN that Saggio suggested to my example above.

Comment: ...Decided against the RIGHT JOIN, they always hurt my brain. Notice how I changed the where clause to check the booking table.